# How to give vertical height manually in bootbox

Tags: bootbox

I want to give vertical height manually in a bootbox prompt.

Here is the bootbox, We can fix it exactly in the center but I want to place it slightly above.

```
      $('#btnNewPra').on('click',function(){
          bootbox.prompt({
            size: "small",
            title: 'Spot',
            margin: '50px' ,
            // centerVertical: true,
            callback: function(result){

            }
          })
        })
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest option is to use the `className` option and some custom CSS, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/6vmjpx3y/

```js
bootbox.prompt({
  size: "small",
  title: 'Spot',
  className: 'mini-box',
  centerVertical: true,
  callback: function(result) {

  }
})
```

and

```css
.mini-box .modal-dialog-centered .modal-content {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

The className value would be whatever makes the most sense for you. There are probably other ways of accomplishing this, but using the `centerVertical` option adds the `.modal-dialog-centered` class to the dialog wrapper. You can then apply a negative margin to the `.modal-content` class (the outermost "visible" part of the modal) to pull the dialog up your desired amount from the center of the viewport.